# Open the same file in different programs

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Private Sub tmrTrade_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTrade.Tick
    tmrTrade.Enabled = False
    Dim TradeCount As Integer = 0
    Dim LastTrade As String = ""
    'Stream File
    Dim fStream As New System.IO.FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString(), IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fStream)
    'Loop Through Lines
    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
        TradeCount = TradeCount + 1
        LastTrade = sReader.ReadLine
    Loop
    'to go back to an array
    fStream.Close()
    sReader.Close()

    'Check if there is a new trade
    If TradeCount = OldTradeCount Then
        'Do nothing no new trades
        tmrTrade.Enabled = True
    Else
        'Disable tmr until trade complete
        tmrTrade.Enabled = False
        'New Trade lets trade

        'Remove date get put or call
        LastTrade = Split(LastTrade, "|")(1)
        OldTradeCount = TradeCount
        'Make the trade
        MakeTrade(LastTrade)

    End If
    'Save Copy
End Sub
```

Basically what this is for is it checks a .txt file that gets a line added to it when a trade is availalbe, what this does is check every 10ms for a change of line on the .txt file.

However the issue i am facing is that if i open up multiple versions of this program, and open the same .txt file it recieves a warning that this file is in use by another program. Please not i only need to read the file not write (metatrader is writing).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the access mode and the share flags to open the file without locking it

[FileShare enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[FileAccess enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Using fStream = new FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, _ 
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Using sReader = new StreamReader(fStream )
    ....

    End Using
End Using
```

I have also enclosed the two stream in a using statement to be sure that they are correctly disposed when you finish to use them